# Why Doesn't This Code Go To the Link?

Tags: html, web, target

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="https://account.mojang.com/login" id="clickHere" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't this html code go to the website https://account.mojang.com/login when I run the html file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you click in the link, nothing is going to happen.

To make it go automatically, use:

```html
<script>window.location.href = 'https://account.mojang.com/login';</script>
```